# Is there an equivalent way to load a GMenu from XML?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, gtk3

I've been using Glade to create my Application menus in the menu-bar for Gtk3.4/3.6 based apps like this:

```
<object class="GtkMenu" id="popup_menu">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="play_album_menu_item">
        <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="tooltip_text" translatable="yes">Play this album</property>
        <property name="label" translatable="yes">Play Album</property>
        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
        <signal name="activate" handler="play_album_menu_item_callback" swapped="no"/>
      </object>
    </child>
```

However, the latest Gnome-based GTK3.8 applications have moved away from GtkMenu/UI-Manager based menu creation and now used GMenu and GMenuItem based creation.

- https://mail.gnome.org/archives/rhythmbox-devel/2013-April/msg00000.html

I've seen Python code-examples that explain how to individually code menu-items.

- https://live.gnome.org/Rhythmbox%20Plugins/Python%20Plugin%20Examples

However I'm trying to save time/increase maintainability & readability by trying to use a similar Glade XML based menu creation process to:

1. Create the GMenu
2. Create a list of GMenuItems
3. Set various properties such as sensitivity, tooltips
4. Connect a signal event

Previously I simply did stuff like:

```
ui = Gtk.Builder()
ui.add_from_file("menufile.xml")
ui.connect_signals(self)
popup_menu = ui.get_object('popup_menu')
```

etc.etc.

Is this possible with GMenu and GMenuItems?

If so, can anyone point me in the correct direction with example Python code samples or links to existing Python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C, the bloatpad example shows the new  XML format that can be used in GtkBuilder files:
https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/examples/bloatpad.c

However, you have to write these by hand. Glade does not yet let you edit GMenus and will just silently remove  nodes.

Comment: Link moved, https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/examples/bp/gtk/menus.ui and https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/examples/bp/bloatpad.c